# Column Datatype Conversion

Tags: postgresql, date

I have a varchar column with text formatted like so "Sun Aug 07 17:43:55 +0000 2011" How would I convert that column in PostgreSQL to a date datatype?

Comment: So you want to remove the time part?  Anyway, you should look at the [`to_date()` function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-formatting.html).

Answer (score 2):

PostgreSQL understands that timestamp format just fine. You can use a cast.

```
regress=> SELECT CAST('Sun Aug 07 17:43:55 +0000 2011' AS timestamp);
      timestamp      
---------------------
 2011-08-07 17:43:55
(1 row)
```

To get just a date, with no time component, you can cast straight to `date` instead of `timestamp`.